# GNOME - Sort menu entries alphabetically

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, menu, appmenu, sort

I wish I could arrange the GNOME application menu alphabetically, but I can't find anything about this online...
Is there by any chance a `gsettings` option or a script to do this?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1408168/305000 for solution for Ubuntu 22.04 GNOME 42.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I went through `dconf-editor` and found a custom array in `org.gnome.shell.app-picker-layout`.
By setting that to value `[]` and restarting `gnome-shell` (or log out then log in again), the applications organize themselves alphabetically.
I still don't know if it should be done after every installed application or if it will stay that way.

Comment: It might stick, as long as you do not drag anything around. You can simplify the reset with a command, `gsettings reset org.gnome.shell app-picker-layout`, which could be put in a script or even a launcher for quick access.