# How do I sort the Gnome 3.38 Show Applications Menu into Alphabetical order?

Tags: gnome

I am using Ubuntu 20.10.
As I've added more and more applications the Show Applications menu in the bottom right is no longer in alphabetical order.

I would like to put all the applications into alphabetical order.

I have tried searching for a solution but can't find a clear answer. I'm new to Gnome 3.38 but not Linux itself and this seems like a very basic feature that has been missed off.

Comment: This behaviour of Gnome Shell is new. The previous versions would automatically put in alphabetic order. Now, the user has to organize his icons. The way described by Matigo is the only way to quickly rearrange everything in alphabetical order, but you also loose custom groups if you created these.

Answer (score 16):

The fastest option would be to put this into the terminal:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell app-picker-layout
```

Logout and Login to see the changes or, if you're in a hurry, restart the window manager by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then enter `r` into the command input (and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Alternatively, you can use `dconf-editor` to control a number of aspects of Gnome. If you don’t already have it installed, you can:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Hope this gives you what you’re looking for

Comment: This does _not_ seem to work on 21.10.

Answer (score 3):

Run following on terminal then log out and log in again to see changes:

```sh
gsettings set org.gnome.shell app-picker-layout "[]"
```

Alternatively, you can put value `[]` on `app-picker-layout` of `org/gnome/shell` using dconf-editor.

Comment: This works on 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this extension as well

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4269/alphabetical-app-grid/